# Why does ambari is showing this kerberos authentication error : AmbariAuthToLocalUserDetailsService

Tags: kerberos, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari, apache-knox

Recently ambari server logs are showing some warnings, We didn't identify any issue yet but logs became unreadable (50 lines/s)

/var/log/ambari-server/ambari-server.log

```
02 Jul 2021 18:43:52,514  INFO [ambari-client-thread-792188] AmbariAuthToLocalUserDetailsService:109 - Translated knox/<knox_gateway>@<REALM> to knox using auth-to-local rules during Kerberos authentication.
02 Jul 2021 18:43:52,515  WARN [ambari-client-thread-792188] AmbariAuthToLocalUserDetailsService:143 - Failed find user account for user with username of knox during Kerberos authentication.
02 Jul 2021 18:43:52,516  WARN [ambari-client-thread-792188] AmbariKerberosAuthenticationFilter:149 - Negotiate Header was invalid: Negotiate YIIDl...
org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException: Failed find user account for user with username of knox during Kerberos authentication.
        at org.apache.ambari.server.security.authentication.kerberos.AmbariAuthToLocalUserDetailsService.createUser(AmbariAuthToLocalUserDetailsService.java:144)
        at org.apache.ambari.server.security.authentication.kerberos.AmbariAuthToLocalUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(AmbariAuthToLocalUserDetailsService.java:110)
        at org.springframework.security.kerberos.authentication.KerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(KerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider.java:66)
        at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:156)
        at org.springframework.security.kerberos.web.authentication.SpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(SpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:145)
        at org.apache.ambari.server.security.authentication.kerberos.AmbariKerberosAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AmbariKerberosAuthenticationFilter.java:167)
        at org.apache.ambari.server.security.authentication.AmbariDelegatingAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AmbariDelegatingAuthenticationFilter.java:120)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.apache.ambari.server.security.authorization.AmbariUserAuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AmbariUserAuthorizationFilter.java:91)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1478)
        at org.apache.ambari.server.api.MethodOverrideFilter.doFilter(MethodOverrideFilter.java:72)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1478)
        at org.apache.ambari.server.api.AmbariPersistFilter.doFilter(AmbariPersistFilter.java:47)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1478)
        at org.apache.ambari.server.security.AbstractSecurityHeaderFilter.doFilter(AbstractSecurityHeaderFilter.java:125)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1478)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.UserAgentFilter.doFilter(UserAgentFilter.java:82)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.GzipFilter.doFilter(GzipFilter.java:294)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1478)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:499)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:427)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
        at org.apache.ambari.server.controller.AmbariHandlerList.processHandlers(AmbariHandlerList.java:212)
        at org.apache.ambari.server.controller.AmbariHandlerList.processHandlers(AmbariHandlerList.java:201)
        at org.apache.ambari.server.controller.AmbariHandlerList.handle(AmbariHandlerList.java:139)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:973)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1035)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:641)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:231)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:696)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:53)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

/var/log/ambari-server/ambari-audit.log

```
2021-07-02T19:01:16.881+0200, User(null), RemoteIp(xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx), Operation(User login), Roles(
), Status(Failed), Reason(Failed find user account for user with username of knox during Kerberos authentication.)
```

**Known issue :**
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMBARI-19767

Ambari version : 2.6.2.2
HDP Version : HDP-2.6.5.1100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause of this issue is when the kerberos authentication is enabled for ambari the logout feature will not work any more.

disabling kerberos authentication on ambari server resolved the issue

```
authentication.kerberos.enabled=false
```